# Array formatting with numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to create a numpy array for mathematical processing and I can't seem to format my code correctly. I have signals from a numpy array: `'A','B','C','D','E'` which I want to be the "headers" or 0th row of my array. The following rows I want to insert value from the same numpy array where the signals are stored, where:

```
values = np.array(dat_arr[:,7])

signals = ['A','B','C','D','E']
```

I know the formatting `[[signals],[values]]` is incorrect as I want an array that outputs something like:

```
[A, B, C, D, E,
 3, 4, 7, 5, 8,
 5, 2, 1, 6, 9]
```

etc.

I am new to programming with numpy and python. Any ideas?

Comment: I just can't to understand what do you  want

Comment: Wait, so you want every `[::5]` to be in column `'A'` and every `[1::5]` to be in `'B'` and so on, without actually making new lists for each rom?  Or do you want a bunch of distinct lists where they line up based on index?

Comment: Are you looking for `hstack`?

Comment: @MCkanequa did you check the answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using [structured types](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html#validating-names). For a text file with the content:

```
A, B, C, D, E
3, 4, 7, 5, 8
5, 2, 1, 6, 9
```

you can do:

```
a = np.genfromtxt('test.txt', names=True, delimiter=',')
```

in order to obtain this kind of structured array, which allows you to do:

```
print(a['A'])
#[ 3.  5.]
```

---

EDIT:

you can obtain your structured array from a list of lists as well, in this case it would be something like:

```
values = [[3, 4, 7, 5, 8],
          [5, 2, 1, 6, 9]]
signals = ['A','B','C','D','E']

a = np.rec.array(values, dtype=list(zip(signals, [float]*len(signals))))
```